# Can't see pose elements when I import the fbx file from Mixamo

Tags: mixamo

I have a problem and it happened for the first time after using Blender for several months.

When I export an animation from Mixamo and I import it into Blender, I see nothing. Even the poses are not showing up.
Do you have any solutions?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Maybe a simple scale problem, press the Home Key to frame all.